# How to detect that file is about to be modified in c#?

Tags: c#, filesystems, monitoring, filesystemwatcher

My .Net application monitors files in specified directory. If any file is about to be modified I need to backup that file.

My goal is to avoid backing up all files in the directory. I want only to backup files that will be modified, it is only a tiny percentage of all files in a folder.

As far as I see the .Net FileSystemWatcher can only detect that file is already modified, so it is too late for me to backup the file at that moment.

How do I detect the moment when the file is about to be modified, so I can backup it?

Comment: You'd need to write a file-system level driver that intercepts the request to the disk and allows you to do something beforehand.

Comment: Mind reading, perhaps? :)

Comment: @eddie_cat No, it's very possible, but a driver is really the only solution.

Comment: [FileSystemWatcher.Changed Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @DJKRAZE Re-read the OP's question; your comment isn't applicable.

Comment: Maybe existing wheel would do -[Volume Shadow Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? (summary on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy) )

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov How would the OP hook into the file system before the write operation happens to trigger a shadow copy? Or is there something configurable in the Shadow Copy system that causes the backup to occur?

Comment: So are you trying to have version control? Using some version control software might help you accomplish this to an extent.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling - my understanding (never actually used it myself) that it already provides versioning of files - so one can go and get older version if needed. I have no idea what requirements are and how much space it uses...

Answer (score -2):

If theres no easy way of intetcepting the write operating  (and I'm pretty sure there isn't, not without writing drivers like some people have commented) you could cheat and use a combination of shaddow coppies and file system watcher. Start with a shadow copy, when the file system watcher detects change, restore the shadow copy, and then do whatever you were intending after.

I know its not a solution just a work around, but youd end up with the same result, a file with the original version after a save.

Comment: You've just described reverting changes.  OP wants to preserve originals, but allow changes.

Comment: Ok yea so i miss read the question. Instead of restoring the shaddow copy. ...backup the shaddow copy?

Comment: The real problem with your suggestion is that OP specifically states "My goal is to avoid backing up all files in the directory. I want only to backup files that will be modified".  Your suggestion is the exact opposite...back them all up all the time.